# HTACCESS How to "cut" URL at one point

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am new to `.htaccess` and I don't understand it well. Recently I have built the following code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v2/
RewriteRule ^api/v2(.*) /api/v2/api.php?input=$1
```

This was in the root public folder (`example.com/.htaccess`). But now I have to create second Rewrite and I want to make `.htaccess` file in `example.com/api/v2/` folder. I tried to remove `/api/v2/` part in each Rewrite Rule, but only thing I got was error 500.

What I want to achieve:

If someone uses this link: `https://example.com/api/v2/test/test/123`, I'd like to make it into `https://example.com/api/v2/api?input=test/test/123` with `.htaccess` located in `example.com/api/v2 folder`.

Comment: By the sounds of it you want to replace the `.htaccess` in the root with the `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory - you are not creating a second rule in addition to the first?

Comment: Just to clarify, the directive you had in the root `.htaccess` file would have rewritten the request to `/api/v2/api?input=/test/test/123` (note the slash prefix on the URL param value), not `/api/v2/api?input=test/test/123` (no slash prefix) as you've stated in your requirements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addressing your existing rule first:

> ```
> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*)
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /api/v2/
> RewriteRule ^api/v2(.*) /api/v2/api.php?input=$1
> ```

The first `RewriteCond` (condition) is entirely superfluous and can simply be removed. The second condition simply asserts that there is a slash after the `v2` and this can be merged with the `RewritRule` *pattern*. So, the above is equivalent to a single `RewriteRule` directive as follows:

```
RewriteRule ^api/v2(/.*) /api/v2/api.php?input=$1 [L]
```

This would internally rewrite the request from `/api/v2/test/test/123` to `/api/v2/api.php?input=/test/test/123` - note the slash prefix on the `input` URL parameter value.

However, unless you have another `.htaccess` file in a subdirectory that also contains mod_rewrite directives then this will create a rewrite loop (500 error).

Also note that you should probably include the `L` flag here to prevent the request being further rewritten (if you have other directives).

> If someone uses this link: `https://example.com/api/v2/test/test/123`, I'd like to make it into `https://example.com/api/v2/api?input=test/test/123` with `.htaccess` located in `example.com/api/v2` folder.

I assume `/api?` is a typo and this should be `/api.php?`. Note also that the slash is omitted from the start of the URL parameter value (different to the rule above).

> I tried to remove `/api/v2/` part in each Rewrite Rule, but only thing I got was error 500.

This is the right idea, however, you need to be careful of rewrite loops (ie. 500 error response) since the rewritten URL is likely matching the regex you are trying to rewrite.

Try the following instead in the `/api/v2/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api\.php$
RewriteRule (.*) api.php?input=$1 [L]
```

The preceding `RewriteCond` directive checks that the request is not already for `api.php`, thus avoiding a rewrite loop, since the *pattern* `.*` will naturally match *anything*, including `api.php` itself.

You could avoid the additional condition by making the regex more specific. For example, if the requested URL-path cannot contain a dot then the above `RewriteCond` and `RewriteRule` directives can be written as a single directive:

```
RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ api.php?input=$1 [L]
```

The regex `[^.]*` matches anything except a dot, so avoids matching `api.php`.

Alternatively, only match the characters that are permitted. For example, lowercase a-z, digits and slashes (which naturally excludes the dot), which covers your test string `test/test/123`:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9/]*)$ api.php?input=$1 [L]
```

Or, if there should always be 3 path segments, `/<letters>/<letters>/<digits>`, then be specific:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]+/[a-z]+/\d+)$ api.php?input=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Hey, I found a problem. My code is:
`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !api\.php$
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$ api.php?input=$1 [L]
`

(I tried to add capital letters support, and I am getting an error)

Request looks like this: https://example.net/api/v2/test/test/123 and result is https://example.net/api/index.php

Comment: The outcome you are seeing doesn't appear to have anything to do with the directive you posted? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file(s)? (In the directive you posted the `RewriteCond` directive is not required - as mentioned above.)

Comment: I have file struct like this: ROOT -> API -> [index.php, V1, V2], (capital = folder name) and result I get is root/api/index.php. + 1 more issue spotted - if I use API word in this, it crashes (regular 404 error). In V2 folder, I only have index.php (empty file) and this .htaccess

Comment: Actually I used this rule - RewriteRule ^([^.]*)$ api.php?input=$1 [L]. I will  validate input manually. Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's great. Although there should be no difference between `^([^.]*)$` and `^([a-zA-Z0-9/]*)$` in terms of the example URL you posted? "In V2 folder, I only have index.php (empty file) and this .htaccess" - But you are rewriting to `api.php` in the V2 folder, not `index.php`, so `api.php` must exist also?